# Canceling background task only makes it go suspended

Tags: c#, uwp, background-process

I unregister my task (I removed the If to make sure all tasks are removed.):

```
foreach (var taskA in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{
    //if (taskA.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
    {
        taskA.Value.Unregister(true);
    }
}
```

Then I try to recreate it, and check if it doesn't exist:

```
private async void LaunchBackground()
{
    await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

    foreach (var taskA in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {
        if (taskA.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
        {
            await new ApplicationTrigger().RequestAsync();
            return;
        }
    }

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

    builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
    builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Background.BackgroundTask";

    ApplicationTrigger _AppTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
    builder.SetTrigger(_AppTrigger);

    builder.Register();

    await _AppTrigger.RequestAsync();
}
```

My task now only a defferal and does some other stuff, releasing it when cancellled:

```
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);
        AddWatched();
    }

    private void OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        _deferral.Complete();
    }
```

But when I try to cancel and unregister the task, it just goes suspended. When I launch it again, it behaves weridly (I think there are two instances of it now, which both try to do the same thing at the same time).

I would ideally like to be able to kill the background task instead of backgronuding it - or if that doesn't work, if the task is suspended it should be unsuspended instead of another one created AND the old one being unsuspended.

Comment: How the task registration and file creation error is related here? Maybe your task tried to create a file and the issue is that the file already exists?

Comment: @Reniuz it seems like I didn't let go of the deferral I got earlier. That said, now I have another issue, because my task does not get canceled, only suspended. When I try to launch it again, I get two instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to cancel, set a Boolean property in ApplicationSettings from your app.
In your background task, periodically check this property during execution and if set, cancel the process.

Comment: And how would I cancel it? All I could find is to call taskA.Value.Unregister(true); but I couldn't find a method that I can call in the process so it cancel/shuts down itself.

Comment: Typically you get a deferral from entry arguments in the background task.  You then call Complete() on the deferral and the task completed/done.

Comment: _deferral.Complete(); is being called at task cancelation, along with any other methods I include in the OnCancelled function. It does not seem to be enough though.

Comment: Alright, it seems like doing complete just marks it for suspension. I also need to implement an if(!canceled) before anything my app might do. And of course set canceled to true in OnCancelled()